# Running program from fileshare in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0, fileshare

What I need to do is execute a program on a remote fileshare inside powershell. An example path would be:

\mycompany\filesharename\folder\program.exe

This program takes a command line arguement, a string, and decrypts it. Problem is I need to decrypt and encrypt literally thousands of lines from different files on different computers. Doing it one at a time through that thing is driving me mad. I've started out with this:

```
clear-host
([string]$step='this') 

$value = Invoke-Command '\\mycompany\fileshare\folder\software\program.exe' $step

write-host $value
```

This is throwing an error:

```
The term '\\mycompany\fileshare\folder\software\program.exe' is not re
cognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
     At C:\Users\Me\Documents\Scripts\test.ps1:3 char:77
+ $value = \\mycompany\fileshare\folder\software\program.exe <<<<  $st
ep
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\mycompany\fileshare...\program.exe:String 
   ) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Eventually the plan is to code a gui, have the script grab the strings I need from the files themselves, and print them inside a local folder. Right now I need to figure out how the heck to use that progam inside my script. Any help?

Comment: Are you really using PS version 1.0 like your tags indicate?

Comment: I will also add that if you are doing this for thousands of files you may want to either run the script on the machine where the exe is or else copy the exe to where you plan to run the script. Each run may not be much network traffic, but thousands of requests might add upp.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Invoke-Expression` instead of `Invoke-Command`:

```powershell
$step='this'
$value = Invoke-Expression "\\mycompany\fileshare\folder\software\program.exe $step"
write-host $value
```